# I need help figuring out how to copy a person's response 100 times in a row

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner; // *Has to be outside of brackets!*

public class Lab_1_3_Class_oops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //I need to request a person's first and last name, then copy it on individual lines after they have entered their input
        //Variables
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Requesting a name
        System.out.print("Please write your first and last name.\n");

        //Allowing a name input
        sc.nextLine();

        //I get as far as allowing text to be entered, but I can't figure out a way to keep that text in the memory long enough to get it copied 100 times without making the person type it 100 times
    }
}
```

I am not looking for direct answers.  I just want to know if what I want is possible with the way I have started and how I would even begin to try something like this.

Comment: You need to assign the input to a variable. I assume sc.nextLine returns a string so you need a string variable to assign that return value to.

Comment: `String personName = sc.nextLine();` Now it's stored in memory. Now look for a `while` loop to print it 100 times. That's all the help I can offer you or I would be harming you

Comment: You have to declare the variable `String s;`, make it readable with `s = sc.nextLine()` and you should create an array or arraylist where you print the value each position (so declare an `int pos = 0` and print it using a `for`)

Comment: By reading some basic book or tutorial?! You are expected to do research prior posting here. And hint: that "computer science" tag made absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Get the name input as a String and use a for loop to print it. I hope I wasn't too direct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a [variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to hold the user's input. Then, you can use a [for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) to do whatever you want any number of times.

```
String name = sc.nextLine(); // Declare a String variable to hold the value
for(int i = 0; i < 1337; i++) { // Use a for loop
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I would go with a `while` loop as it's easier to understand when learning to program, however those links to docs are helpful although I would show at least how the variable is created into your answer

Answer (score 0):

Declare a [variable](https://javaranch.com/campfire/StoryCups.jsp) to hold the user's input, then put it in a [loop](https://javaranch.com/drive/loop.html)(print it from there)

Comment: @Jelliebean71 please use mark as answer to prevent people from going to this forum in unanswered questions

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all so much!  The way I fixed it was by declaring

```
int num = 1;
```

and then creating a while loop

```
while (num <= 100) {
        System.out.println(name);
        num = num + 1;
    }
```

I really appreciate everyone's help without actually telling me the answer.